# PARSER_ERROR while building services in liferay

Tags: liferay, google-visualization

While deployment getting the error for method which is having `List<List<object>>` return type. Its not compiling and throwing the PARSER_ERROR

```
08:35:51,817 ERROR [main][java:355] PARSER_ERROR
 [echo] D:\Gitlab\OR3-Dev-Core\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ee-sp17\portlets\onrule-extension-projects-task-service-portlet\ServiceBuilder.temp:1684:13: expecting SEMI, found 'getDonutChartData'
 [echo]     at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.antlr.InternalJavaParser.classField(InternalJavaParser.java:3081)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.antlr.InternalJavaParser.classBlock(InternalJavaParser.java:2457)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.antlr.InternalJavaParser.classDefinition(InternalJavaParser.java:710)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.antlr.InternalJavaParser.typeDefinitionInternal(InternalJavaParser.java:632)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.antlr.InternalJavaParser.typeDefinition(InternalJavaParser.java:465)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.antlr.InternalJavaParser.parse(InternalJavaParser.java:296)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.JavaRecognizer.parse(JavaRecognizer.java:588)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.Jalopy.parse(Jalopy.java:1212)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.Jalopy.format(Jalopy.java:1044)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.Jalopy.format(Jalopy.java:1017)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.writeFile(ServiceBuilder.java:448)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.writeFile(ServiceBuilder.java:364)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder._createServiceSoap(ServiceBuilder.java:3236)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.<init>(ServiceBuilder.java:810)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.main(ServiceBuilder.java:229)
 [echo] 08:35:51,942 ERROR [main][io:1071] UNKNOWN_ERROR
 [echo] expecting EOF, found 'return'
 [echo] D:\Gitlab\OR3-Dev-Core\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ee-sp17\portlets\onrule-extension-projects-task-service-portlet\ServiceBuilder.temp:1719:33: expecting EOF, found 'return'
 [echo] Nested Exception is: D:\Gitlab\OR3-Dev-Core\liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2-ee-sp17\portlets\onrule-extension-projects-task-service-portlet\ServiceBuilder.temp:1719:33: expecting EOF, found 'return'  at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211)
 [echo]     at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.antlr.InternalJavaParser.parse(InternalJavaParser.java:308) at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.antlr.InternalJavaParser.parse(InternalJavaParser.java:308)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.JavaRecognizer.parse(JavaRecognizer.java:588)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.Jalopy.parse(Jalopy.java:1212)   at de.hunsicker.jalopy.language.JavaRecognizer.parse(JavaRecognizer.java:588)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.Jalopy.format(Jalopy.java:1044)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.Jalopy.parse(Jalopy.java:1212)
 [echo]     at de.hunsicker.jalopy.Jalopy.format(Jalopy.java:1017)  at de.hunsicker.jalopy.Jalopy.format(Jalopy.java:1044)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.writeFile(ServiceBuilder.java:448)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.writeFile(ServiceBuilder.java:364)    at de.hunsicker.jalopy.Jalopy.format(Jalopy.java:1017)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder._createServiceSoap(ServiceBuilder.java:3236)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.<init>(ServiceBuilder.java:810)   at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.writeFile(ServiceBuilder.java:448)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.main(ServiceBuilder.java:229) at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.writeFile(ServiceBuilder.java:364)
 [echo] Building ProjectTaskDependency
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder._createServiceSoap(ServiceBuilder.java:3236)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.<init>(ServiceBuilder.java:810)
 [echo]     at com.liferay.portal.tools.servicebuilder.ServiceBuilder.main(ServiceBuilder.java:229)
```

Comment: method is public List<List<Object>> getBarChartData(long project_id)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried generic classes, especially not doubly-generic ones, as return types. You might have found a limitation in types that ServiceBuilder can handle.

As you don't post your code, I'm assuming that your method that returns a `List<List<Object>>` is within a `*LocalServiceImpl`? You might want to post your code (as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to make your situation easier to reproduce.